# Single Linked List Insert at the tail

Tags: java, linked-list, adt

Every time I run this, it returns a bunch of: null, null, null for the items when I test the function out.

```
//enqueue()
//adds newItem to the back of this Queue

public void insertItemLast(Object newItem){//make sure that it is not empty so we can do the cool stuff in here
    if(newItem == null)
        return;//user inputs nothing
    else {
        Node P = new Node(newItem);
        P.next = null;
        if(head == null){
            head = P;
            tail = P;
            //tail.next = null;
        }else{
            tail.next = new Node(newItem);
            tail = new Node(newItem);

            //tail.next = null;

        }

    }
    numItems++;
}//end enqueque
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two different links instead of just one.

Your else should be :

```
 } else {
    tail.next = new Node(newItem);
    tail = tail.next;
}
```

Actually, you can make it even simpler. Just use P for the new link of the list in all cases :

```
public void insertItemLast(Object newItem){
    if(newItem == null)
        return;//user inputs nothing
    else {
        Node P = new Node(newItem);
        P.next = null;
        if(head == null) {
            head = P;
            tail = P;
        } else {
            tail.next = P;
            tail = P;
        } 
    }
    numItems++;
}//end enqueque
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly assigned a new `Node` to `tail.next`, but you didn't update `tail`; you instead assigned another new `Node` to `tail`, effectively breaking the tail off of the list.

To advance the old `tail` to the new `tail` -- the newly inserted `Node` -- replace

```
tail = new Node(newItem);
```

with

```
tail = tail.next;
```